# What is the way to use Angular4 library with Angular6 project?

Tags: angular, angular6

We are currently transitioning from Angular4 to Angular6. 
Our project depends on **2 other libraries which are built on Angular4 and they don't have any plans to upgrade it to Angular6.**

When we upgraded our project to Angualr6, we started getting the following error -

`ERROR in node_modules/foundation-services/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.`

When researched, I found out that these errors exist due to incompatible versions of Angular between libraries and project.
Is there a way to have it working?

Comment: People who are downvoting, could you please state the reason for the downvote?
Don't you think it is a real problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I suggest you to:

1. Update each library to latest version
2. Delete *node_modules*
3. Angular 6 change file configuration format. You can see [this link](https://update.angular.io/) to migrate from version 4 to version 6.

Comment: That's the problem, the libraries are not gonna be updated to Angular6 anytime soon. I need some workaround.

Comment: I've some library that depends from an older version of Angular, but I have no problem to migrate angular CLI to version 6 and use them. I suggest you try (if you are on a Source Version Control you can always go back).

Answer (score 0):

you go to update angular 2,4,5 to angular latest version go with this link https://update.angular.io